# Alter deploy address for contract created with `new` keyword

Tags: contract-deployment, forge

I have a forge test that contains `new MyContract();`. However the address that MyContract is deployed to just so happens to be in use by another contract, so the test fails.

Is there a way to alter the code such that the `new MyContract();` call deploys the contract at a new address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the create2 syntax to deploy a contract to a predictable address using a salt. The address changes depending on the salt.

```
bytes32 someSalt;
new MyContract{salt: someSalt}();
```

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/control-structures.html#salted-contract-creations-create2

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/create2/